# GTA online weapon bug

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Okay this may seem wierd but i have faced this twice, i have gta 5 for pc and after i played online for few minutes i at times get guns which should not be there for me.

For instance i got a Rail gun, are not rail guns ps4 xone exclusive ?another instance is that, i am currently on level 27 and i got that sniper rifle with advanced scope(the one which unlocks at level 90)i had not even purchased it.

Has anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you've described, it is likely that the online lobby you were in had a hacker/modder. These people are able to do a lot of crazy stuff, including spawning weapons that you can pick up.

These weapons that you've picked up should not persist between sessions, so re-starting the game or entering a new lobby *should* remove them from your inventory.

Rockstar has, thus far, been largely ineffective at stopping many of these hackers. But if you manage to capture video proof of someone hacking (often difficult unless they're being obvious), you should submit it to Rockstar support by [opening a new support request](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).